# Размещение сцены в Tab

Tags: java, javafx

Есть ряд окон, которые я перевожу на вкладки. Но при простом переносе, они не хотят растягиваться. Подскажите что можно сделать в коде. (Буду очень рад если не придется бегать и править все `.fxml` )

```
Tab newOne = new Tab(name);
newOne.setClosable(true);
FXMLLoader fl = new FXMLLoader(address);
fl.setResources(new Utilities.MapResourceBundle(in));
Parent root = fl.load();
newOne.setContent(bp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от того, чем именно является Parent.

Если не сильно заморачиваться, то можно проставить в контент [AnchorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) и в этот `AnchorPane` добавить чайлда вашего `Parent`, растянув его на весь `AnchorPane` ( статическими методами AnchorPane.setBootomAnchor(root, 0.0), и тоже самое для Left, Rigth и Top)